# How to create a keybinding to a file in Emacs?

Tags: key-bindings, files, find-file, android

I have a frequently opened file in Emacs, which is deep inside my device. I want to bind the F5 key(or any other key) to open that file, how can I do that?
(Using android to run emacs. [GNURoot, Wheezy. ])

Comment: Try [File Register](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Registers.html)

Comment: Not a single keybinding, but [bookmarks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html) are also useful.

Comment: Here are four (4) options in the link to the following thread entitled **How can I open quickly a file in emacs?** -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284395/2112489

Answer (score 3):

Try bookmarks.

- visit the file
- add a bookmark to it with `C-x r m` or by running `bookmark-set`
- jump to the bookmark at any time with `C-x r b` (`M-x bookmark-jump`) or display a list of all your bookmarks with `C-x r l` (`M-x bookmark-bmenu-list`)

You can, of course, also bind `F5` (or any other key) to a function that calls `bookmark-jump` with a given bookmark name.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing could be:

```el
;; quickly open some files
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6> h") (lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/.emacs.d/lisp/init_hooks.el")))
```

Another way of doing:

```el
(require 'ido) ; part of emacs

(defvar xah-filelist nil "alist for files i need to open frequently. Key is a short abbrev string, Value is file path string.")

(setq xah-filelist
      '(
        ("3emacs" . "~/web/ergoemacs_org/emacs/blog.html" )
        ("4code" . "~/web/xahlee_info/comp/blog.html" )
        ("keys" . "~/git/xah_emacs_init/xah_emacs_keybinding.el" )
        ("download" . "~/Downloads/" )
        ("pictures" . "~/Pictures/" )
        ;; more here
        ) )

(defun xah-open-file-fast ()
  "Prompt to open a file from `xah-filelist'.
URL `http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hotkey_open_file_fast.html'
Version 2015-04-23"
  (interactive)
  (let ((ξabbrevCode
         (ido-completing-read "Open:" (mapcar (lambda (ξx) (car ξx)) xah-filelist))))
    (find-file (cdr (assoc ξabbrevCode xah-filelist)))))
```

Courtesy of [ErgoEmacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hotkey_open_file_fast.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bookmarks for this purpose, together with the `headlong` package (to select the bookmark much faster). See [my blog post](http://oremacs.com/2015/01/06/rushing-headlong/).

One cool feature that I recently added to my config is `ido-use-virtual-buffers` / `ivy-use-virtual-buffers`: if you set them to t, then `ido-switch-buffer` / `ivy-switch-buffer` will actually use all your bookmarks.